# Complete end-to-end reference guide

Tags: grammar, resources, characters

I was wondering if there are websites for learning Chinese language that are similar to the following made for the Japanese language:

- [IMABI](https://www.imabi.net/)
- [Learn Japanese – Tae Kim's Guide to Learning Japanese](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/)

They are both a reference for grammar and writing system.

Answer (score 1):

What is your research effort?

There are many websites that teach aspects of the Chinese language *Putonghua*.
One example is the [Wikibook Chinese](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Chinese_(Mandarin)).

Other sites provide dictionaries and, more importantly, example sentences, like [Ichacha](http://www.ichacha.net/).

You won't, however, find a "complete" or "end-to-end" guide for any natural, living language. Despite many people stressing the simplicity of Chinese grammar, the fun only really starts after completing the basic structures.